# Simultaneously connect Mac to 2 APs... one via 5.8GHz 802.11ac, the other via 2.4GHz 802.11n or wifi direct?

Tags: wireless-networking, mac

I'm trying to find a way to wirelessly connect a recent-vintage (2023 M3) Macbook Pro to an esp32 in a way that WON'T screw up its ability to remain connected to a 5.8GHz 802.11ac access point.

I originally planned to use Bluetooth SPP, but I'm having serious problems with dropped/mangled bytes at 230400 baud, so I'm now exploring other options... like wifi.

As I understand it, many/most/all of the actual baseband chips used to implement wifi in newer devices are *physically* capable of treating 2.4GHz and 5.8GHz wifi as two completely separate and independent devices. Assuming that's correct... do recent-vintage Macbooks *have* chips with that flexibility, and does Apple provide any way to *use* it? Say, using the 5.8GHz radio modem to connect to a normal 802.11ac access point for normal networking, and...

- use the 2.4GHz radio modem to connect to an esp32 via wifi direct, or
- use the 2.4GHz radio modem to connect to an esp32 pretending to be an access point with address like 172.14.42.1, and somehow configure OSX to route all traffic that isn't going to 172.14.42.* (or even one single IP address, since traffic sent to the esp32 will be consumed by it) to the "main" AP?